# Convert to numeric string with colons and commas in R

Tags: r

Please, help with the following example:

```
a <- "1:4, 20:25, 30:40"
```

I need to convert `a` to a numeric vector as if I do not have quotation marks in `a`, I mean this:

```
> c(1:4, 20:25, 30:40)
 [1]  1  2  3  4 20 21 22 23 24 25 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
```

Comment: `eval(parse(text=paste0("c(", a, ")")))`

Comment: Another option is `library(gsubfn);strapply(a, "(\\d+):(\\d+)", ~seq(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y), by = 1))[[1]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unlist(lapply(unlist(strsplit(a, ",")), function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
# [1]  1  2  3  4 20 21 22 23 24 25 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
```

And here'a another approach in base R that does not use `eval(parse())`

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(x = a, split = ","), function(x){
    unlist(lapply(strsplit(x = x, split = ":"), function(y)
        as.numeric(y[1]):as.numeric(y[2])))
}))
# [1]  1  2  3  4 20 21 22 23 24 25 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
```