# Return TRUE/FALSE if range is within list of ranges R

Tags: r, range

I have a range of numbers

```
rg <- 25:46
```

I need to check whether any numbers from that range falls within a string of ranges and return true/false

```
lrg <- "1:26,48:56,78:99,121:143,165:204,226:243,265:268,290:316"
```

What i have tried is

```
for (i in str_split(lrg,',')){ print(noquote(i) %in% rg)}
```

but this always returns `FALSE`
probably something simple im missing here

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082345/convert-to-numeric-string-with-colons-and-commas-in-r

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R solution.

```r
rg <- 25:46
lrg <- "1:26,48:56,78:99,121:143,165:204,226:243,265:268,290:316"

l <- lapply(strsplit(lrg, ",")[[1]], \(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
sapply(l, \(x) any(rg %in% x))
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Beware though,

```r
fortunes::fortune(106)
#> 
#> If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
#>    -- Thomas Lumley
#>       R-help (February 2005)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

How can a string like `lrg` be part of a real life question or problem?

---

## Edit

Inspired in [yuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73641008/8245406) and [r2evans' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73640861/return-true-false-if-range-is-within-list-of-ranges-r/73640916#comment130041868_73641008). In fact, my code above rewritten as a pipe.

```r
strsplit(lrg, ",") |>
  unlist() |>
  lapply(\(x) parse(text = x) |> eval()) |>
  sapply(\(x) any(rg %in% x))
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rg <- 25:46
lrg <- "1:26,48:56,78:99,121:143,165:204,226:243,265:268,290:316"
l = str_split(lrg, ",", simplify = T) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x) parse(text = x) %>% eval()) %>% 
  unlist()
any(rg %in% l)
```

Comment: `library(stringr); library(magrittr)`

Comment: Right. Or just `library(tidyverse)`.

Answer (score 1):

Base R using `findIntervals`:

```
!all(!findInterval(rg, c(ints <- as.numeric(strsplit(lrg, "\\,|:")[[1]]), ints[length(ints)])) %% 2)
```

This will work if the ranges are non-overlapping.